# Is "Comments" Site Column in Sharepoint of Plain Text type or Rich Text type?

Tags: sharepoint, site-column

There is an out of the box "Comments" Site Column in SharePoint. I can't figure out that whether it is of Plain Text type or of Rich Text type, as I need to have a Plain Text Multiple Line of Text field of "Comments" title in a Custom list and if an out of box solution exists, I would be able to use that directly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Comments" site column from the "Core Document Columns" group of site columns is a plain text (not rich text) multi-line text field.